# How to add 'image' field to Review / MedicalClinic?

Tags: image, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have recently noticed that I am now getting an error in the Google Structured data testing tool for my Review and MedicalClinic Schema.org. I was not getting this error a week ago.

The issue present is that it's saying I don't have an `image` field, or a value for the `image` field. What is the syntax I would need to add to get the image field in the MedicalClinic and Review types?

```html
<span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/MedicalClinic">
  <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://www.productontology.org/id/Travel_medicine" />
  <span itemprop="name">Passport Health Baltimore Travel Clinic</span>
</span>
```

My page in the SDTT: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.passporthealthusa.com%2Flocations%2Fmd%2Fbaltimore%2F162%2F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `URL` value

If you want to provide a `URL` value for [Schema.org’s `image` property](http://schema.org/image), you can use one of these elements in HTML+Microdata:

- `src` attribute of the **`img`** element
- `href` attribute of the **`a`**/**`area`**/**`link`** elements
- `data` attribute of the **`object`** element

(per [WHATWG’s HTML Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html#values); omitting elements that don’t make sense for images)

So for example:

```html
<link itemprop="image" href="image.png" />
```

#### `ImageObject` value

If you want to provide an `ImageObject` value (instead of a URL value), you can use any element that can have suitable child elements, e.g., a `div`:

```html
<div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <img itemprop="contentUrl" src="image.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for the answer! I will try implementing in the near future and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @CarterSteinhoff: I don’t know. It could be a bug in the testing tool, or it could be a new requirement that is not yet [documented](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews). If you open the ["Simple review" example](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews#review-snippet-examples), it has an `image` property, and if you remove it, the same error appears.

Comment: Ya, just got off the phone with a google rep. It's a new requirement.